# Trying to index data from a CSV

Tags: python, indexing

I started working on a simple program some time ago, and I have gotten back into it. What I am trying to do here is use an index to manipulate the order in which data from a CSV prints. When I run this code, I get "IndexError: list index is out of range". What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks in advance.

```
import csv

mags = csv.reader(open("mags.csv","rU"))

for row in mags:

     print [titles.upper( ) for titles in row]

     print [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]
```

Comment: The code you have pasted contains error, the variable `mags` is not defined. After replacing it to members, I have found no error. What is the content of CSV file?

Comment: Strange. Are you saying that you no longer get the indexerror if you replace the 'mags' variable? The CSV contains titles and dates of magazines.

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen the `IndexError` with my own CSV file, so I am wondering does some lines in CSV file cause this problem. Could you please paste some lines form the CSV file? Or you can print the `row` out before print the list, which can help to locate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error looks like it is on the last line of code. It looks like your loop encounters an empty row with 0 fields, so row[index] throws the IndexError. Or perhaps the row only has 1 field, so row[index] throws the error when index is 1. This would fix it:

```
if len(row) >= 2:
    print [row[index] for index in (1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation in csv.reader() each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. I guess that in your file you have empty fields or lines.

So you should do something like:

```
members = csv.reader(open("mags.csv","rU"))
for row in members:
 for index in (1, 0):
   if index < len(row):
      print row[index]
```

But you could also use:

```
members = csv.reader(open("mags.csv","rU"))
for row in members:
  row.reverse()
  for element in row:
     print element
```

Comment: Thanks ILYA. This definitely reversed the order of the data like I wanted. Now I need to figure out how to get to print on the same line.

Comment: Instead of second loop you could use: `print ','.join(row)`